# Grafana showing wrong data in graph for disk usage

Tags: grafana, graphite, collectd, graphite-carbon

Grafana is showing wrong disk use percentage in graph. Currently my glusterfs disk usage is 8%, but on graph its showing 7%.

Below is the metrics which I am currently using.

{
      "hide": true,
      "target": "sumSeries(collectd.gls-*-01.df-gluster.df_complex-used)",
      "refId": "A"
    },
    {
      "hide": true,
      "target": "sumSeries(collectd.gls-*-01.df-gluster.df_complex-{free,used})",
      "refId": "B"
    },
    {
      "hide": false,
      "target": "asPercent(#A, #B)",
      "refId": "C

Also I am unable to see percent_bytes-used metrics in collectd directory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ReportReserved in your collectd configuration you might need to take account for reserved disk space. If it is true (default on collectd > 4) you will have to change your second metric to: 'df_complex-{free,used,reserved}'

Comment: Thanks Popieluch. Also one more issue which I am facing is that I am unable to save the json file. If I am making changes in the file after some time it is getting back to the same values.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to save the json file. If I am making changes in the file after some time it is getting back to the same values.